Cross Entropy Benchmarking Fidelity bounds
I'm studying various methods of Fidelity XEB calculations. Using this guide I derived formula for Fidelity XEB for one random circuit
\begin{equation} 
    f = \frac{\sum_i p_{\textrm{ideal}}(x_i) p_{\textrm{exp}}(x_i) - 1/2^n \sum_i p_{\textrm{ideal}}(x_i)}{\sum_i p_{\textrm{ideal}}(x_i) p_{\textrm{ideal}}(x_i) - 1/2^n \sum_i p_{\textrm{ideal}}(x_i)}.
\end{equation}
I'm curious now what are the upper and lower bounds of this function. Every paper I found on the subject states that typical bounds for fidelity XEB are [0,1], but, for the provided function I can always take some experimental and ideal probabilities which yield fidelity below 0 or greater than 1 (at least in the case of 1 qubit system). Am I misunderstanding something about Fidelity XEB, or is it indeed possible for this metric to exceed the [0, 1] range?

No, you are not missing something. We have tried to prove similar statement for filtered randomized benchmarking http://arxiv.org/abs/2212.06181 (which can be seen as a generalization of XEB), and one can generally construct adversarial noise which increases the XEB. Similar things are true for shadows btw http://arxiv.org/abs/2310.19947. What you read is the intuitive expectation, which you can prove for local, gate-independent noise (but on average). A proof for more general noise models is however missing to the best of my knowledge.

Thank you for the answer. I also had thoughts that noise-model can induce some problems. I think your comment fully answers my question.
